# Can I daisy chain a single-plug extension lead to another extension lead?

Tags: voltage

Since I only have single plug sockets in my room and the layout is difficult, I have to daisy chain my extension leads.

I’m not sure if this reduces risk at all, but I need some clarification on whether anything will start a fire.

I am using a single-plug extension lead (just room for one socket) connected to another extension lead.

This single-plug is going to be used for my iPhone charger.

Is there going to be any major risk in doing this, or should I accept the risk here?

I really don’t want to start a fire.

I know nothing about electronics.

Comment: The problem with allowing this is, in the winter you'll get cold, and (you or someone else) will attempt to plug a heater into that double-extension cord.  There's a reason some devices have very short cords (coffee maker, dryer, deep fryer) - a long cord would introduce too much electrical loss, and loss always equals heat.  That heat, if crammed under a bed or behind a dresser, is a recipe for a fire.

Answer (score 1):

For an iPhone-charger I really wouldn't worry.

I, too, remember Tom & Jerry Cartoons warning us about the dangers of daisy-chaining power strips, but these are from times with worse in-wall wiring, worse fusing, and less reliable / more brittle plastics. At least for continental Europe and the UK, you'll be having a hard time finding an extension cord whose connectors are realistically not able to carry the current your outlet is fused for (10A / 16A). And: while every connector certainly is another risk for broken contacts that get hot and melt, I've practically only seen that happen in greymarket installation sockets in my whole life (and in cases where people let loose strands of multi-strand wire fly around in outlets – one of the reasons why electrical codes expect you to have ferrules on multi-strand wire before you screw it into a fixture of any kind).